# How to change resource files to a custom format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I used to make games in Microsoft's XNA. XNA had a ContentPipeline project built into it that automatically built all your image files to .XNB files. This had the advantage that users couldn't trivially modify image files (e.g. in Paint).

Now that I'm coding in C#/OpenTK, I use the Copy-To-Output functionality in Visual Studio to copy my image, sound and font files for runtime use by my application. However I lose the protection that a custom format granted.

My question is how can I create something similar? Is there an off-the-shelf library I can use, or code I can write to create this?

Compression isn't especially important to me - just changing the extension to something custom is all I'm really after.

Comment: Changing the file extention will not prevent users to modify your images

Comment: No but it will put them off if it is not trivially obvious e.g. when they are a .PNG. If the answer is "you can do this but the better answer is also to encrypt/compress them, and here is a library to encrypt/decrypt/compress/decompress", I'd love to hear that.

Comment: You can use a post-build event with anything you'll like, for example a command line that will zip the file with a password or whatever. At runtime you can then decompress it with a zip c# library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expands upon Kyle's answer and your question to him about encryption routines.

If you want a simple Encrypt/Decrypt pattern, you can use this one. The keyString is your Salt that will allow you to decrypt the data at a later time. I got this code from a blog post about encryption, and while there may be better routines out there today, this one works well.

```
    public static byte[] EncryptData(string keyString, byte[] dataToEncrypt)
    {
        if (keyString.IsNullOrEmptyTrimmed())
            throw new ArgumentNullException("keyString", "You must provide a key string for salting.");

        if (dataToEncrypt == null)
            return null;

        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] encryptedData;
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] tdesKey = hashProvider.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(keyString));

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdesAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

        tdesAlgorithm.Key = tdesKey;
        tdesAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdesAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;


        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = tdesAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
            encryptedData = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(dataToEncrypt, 0, dataToEncrypt.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            tdesAlgorithm.Clear();
            hashProvider.Clear();
        }

        return encryptedData;
    }

    public static byte[] DecryptData(string keyString, byte[] encyptedData)
    {
        if (encyptedData == null)
            return null;

        byte[] decryptedData;
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] tdesKey = hashProvider.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(keyString));

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdesAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdesAlgorithm.Key = tdesKey;
        tdesAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdesAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = tdesAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
            decryptedData = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encyptedData, 0, encyptedData.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            tdesAlgorithm.Clear();
            hashProvider.Clear();
        }

        return decryptedData;
    }
```

Comment: This looks good. I will try it tonight and upon success grant the bounty. Can I ask: presumably I will need to create a separate application to convert the files in my Content folder into the encrypted bytes, then save them to disk in the bin directory - which I can run using a post-build event? Or maybe I could use #if DEBUG preprocessor directive to run the "saving" (Encrypt) part of the code only in Debug mode?

Comment: Also: how can I protect my "key"? Is just having a static constant in the application sufficient?

Comment: How and when to encrypt is another question. I would recommend a separate utility application to do it for you that you run whenever you add new images. Place new images in a source folder outside of your application but in your source tree, run the utility app, it outputs the encrypted files to the project to be included. This way you can test everything in debug mode.

Comment: As to the protection of the key, obfuscation of how this is done will impact the security of your key. Without using a service it can be decompiled, but without internet access you lose all images as they won't be accessible. Using the static is a good starting point, but you probably want to pass it through some processing before using it as a key. Examples of this include ROT-13, reversing the string, etc.

Comment: You could also build the key on the fly using things like the app name, version, project guid, etc., but this would require re-encrypting the files prior to each release to ensure they are using the new key. Added benefit: Replaced images only work for the one version they were done for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a .png file loading from disc, getting encrypted and writing back to disk as .hpng (the H is for Haighstrom, obviously). I have also tested reading the .hpng, decrypting it, and writing it back to disk as a different .png - which can then be viewed in Windows Preview. As to how to deploy the solution, you have given me some good ideas, and I can probably manage from here. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is simply don't worry about it since custom extensions grant little to no protection anyway. Many programs will ignore the extension and let you edit the file regardless.

If you do need some (pseudo) protection, a common option is to encrypt the files and decrypt them at runtime. However, malicious users could still get to the files by reverse engineering your code.

Comment: Does C# offer a simple encryption library, and if so can you share a snippet? Or can you recommend a library? I just want something simple that would put average joes off from "seeing" the image files in the content folder and being tempted to edit them.